# Google Maps API - Autocomplete Predictions for USA only

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I'm using Google Maps API example called '[Retrieving Autocomplete Predictions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-queryprediction)'. And I can't figure out how to filter it so it only returns places in the USA. I see how I could do it with the other examples...

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var options = {
      types: ['(cities)'],
      componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'}
    };

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to apply it to my example. Here is my code...

```
function GetAddressPredictions(Search) {
    var displaySuggestions = function (predictions, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        return;
    }
    predictions.forEach(function (prediction) {
        PredictionArray.push(prediction);
    });
};
var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
service.getQueryPredictions({input: Search}, displaySuggestions);
}
```

I tried this but it didn't work.

```
function GetAddressPredictions(Search) {
    var displaySuggestions = function (predictions, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        return;
    }
    predictions.forEach(function (prediction) {
        PredictionArray.push(prediction);
    });
};
var options = {
    types: ['(cities)'],
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'}
      };
    var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
    service.getQueryPredictions({input: Search, options}, displaySuggestions);
}
```

Any Ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are so very close but unfortunately to get this specific behavior you need to use `getPlacePredictions()` instead of `getQueryPredictions()`. This allows you to use [AutocompletionRequest](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#QueryAutocompletionRequest) which has `componentRestrictions` however [QueryAutocompletionRequest](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#QueryAutocompletionRequest) does not support `componetRestictions` and you must fall back to either using `bounds` to limit the scope of the search to a box or `location` to bias the search to prefer locations near a point.

Here is the solution with `getPlacePredictions()`:

```
  var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
  var options = {
    input: Search,
    types: ['(cities)'],
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'}
  };
  service.getPlacePredictions(options , displaySuggestions);
```

You can add `location` or `bounds` as keys to the options object if you must do this with `getQueryPredictions()`

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The function [getQueryPredictions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompleteService) takes a [QueryAutocompletionRequest](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#QueryAutocompletionRequest) object as its parameter, and QueryAutocompletionRequest doesn't have a property to restrict it to a specific country.

That said, you can simply append ' United States' or ' usa' to the query before sending:

```
service.getQueryPredictions({
   input: 'pizza near Syd' + ' usa'
}, displaySuggestions);
```

If you don't want the ", USA" to show within the returned results, you can remove it with JavaScript's replace function:

```
predictions.forEach(function(prediction) {
   var li = document.createElement('li');
   li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(prediction.description.replace(', USA', '')));
   document.getElementById('results').appendChild(li);
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/sdz4yssL/2/

Also note that if there is a risk of the search terms already including USA or a variation thereof, then you will need to remove any occurrences from the search terms first (typically using regex to ignore case sensitivity), otherwise searching for something like "pizza usa usa" will return no results:

```
input: (' ' + 'pizza near us Syd usa United States US' + ' ').replace(/ usa /ig,' ').replace(/ US /ig,' ').replace(/ united states /ig,' ') + ' usa'
```

(I've added a space before and after the query so that the replace functions will still match at the beginning and the very end)

Comment: I had that idea before, but the problem is, in the beginning as you type, its returns results with the letters US in it.... See example here... https://s23.postimg.org/idefab67v/Screen_Shot_2017-07-17_at_8.08.17_AM.png - This really limits the ability of it. Any other solutions?

Comment: My regex matches on [space]US[space], so US-41, which doesn't have a trailing space shouldn't be a problem. Have you tried it with my code?

Comment: If you were you appending 'US' to the query in the screenshot, you would be better using ' USA' as I've done, or even ' United States'

Comment: Wait, so how to I remove listings like US-41? What part of your code does that?

Comment: I also tried US, USA, and United States. They all return results with that in their name. How do I fix this? Are you sure there is no way to use country restrictions?

Comment: If you check my jsfiddle I add " USA" to the search and then I remove it from displaying in the search results at the end, is that what you mean?  With US-41 etc. in your screenshot, you're asking google to search the whole of the USA for just a number; no other context for it. If I was Google search I wouldn't know what you're looking for. What were you expecting to be returned?

Comment: I see what you mean. But it still effects the search. It puts listings with the letter 'US' in the beginning. I guess there is no other way. Thank you so much for your help, I gave you a up mark to you answer. But since I didn't actually solve the problem as I tried your solution before I asked the question, am I still required to select a winner to the bounty?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149426/discussion-between-k-scandrett-and-nachshon-f).

Answer (score 2):

With a bit of searching it was possible to find the solution.

The request was approved and released of earlier this year:  [Google Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35826806)

The documentation of such information can be read from here: [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#add_autocomplete)

**Implementation:**

HTML :

```
<div id="text">
  Search Place:
</div>

<div id="locationField">
  <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter text" type="text" />
</div>


<div id="map"></div>
```

Restrict to which country using a global variable, UK for uk, US for Americas etc...

```
var countryRestrict = {
  'country': 'uk'
};
var autocomplete;
```

Auto complete is then constructed using the following:

```
 autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
     (
      document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
      componentRestrictions: countryRestrict
    });
  places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', onPlaceChanged);
```

When the text changes we call the onPlacesChanged function:

```
function onPlaceChanged() {
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  if (place.geometry) {
    map.panTo(place.geometry.location);
    map.setZoom(5);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: place.geometry.location,
      map: map,
    });
  } else {
    document.getElementById('autocomplete').placeholder = 'Enter a Value';
  }
}
```

This calls the get place function and adds a marker to the value you clicked on.

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/hn8091fk/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this:

```
function GetAddressPredictions(Search) {

    var displaySuggestions = function(predictions, status) {
        if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            return;
        }

        predictions.forEach(function(prediction) {
            PredictionArray.push(prediction);
        });
    };

    var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
    service.getQueryPredictions({ 
            input: Search, 
            types: ['(cities)'], 
            componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'} 
        }, displaySuggestions);
}
```

Comment: Sorry. Didn't work. It's still returning results from other countries. There is no errors in the console, so there is little I can give you.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to above, [AutocompleteService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompleteService) takes EITHER [QueryAutocompletionRequest](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#QueryAutocompletionRequest) OR [AutocompletionRequest](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompletionRequest) so I think the way you are passing your options is wrong. Is it not simply:

```
var options = {
    input: Search, 
    types: ['(cities)'],
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'}
};

var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
service.getQueryPredictions(options, displaySuggestions);
```

Please also keep in mind that this is all for *prediction biasing* you cannot ask PAC to exclude results, only bias.

Comment: I did what you said, but it didn't work. One of the first results is in Spain. I see no difference in the results then my original code. Thanks anyway for trying.

Comment: @nachshonf sorry about that. Is there any chance of creating a jsfiddle or similar to have a look at it? I've not used Google PAC using these methods before